# Why Am I getting this key error?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

[image]I have no idea what im doing wrong here but I keep  getting a key error, cant figure out why, what am i missing?

```
campers = {'pb' : 'Pooder Bennet', 'jf' : 'Jupiter Fargo',
           'rb' : 'Randy Buffet', 'bl' : 'Botany Lynn',
       'bt' : 'Boris Tortavich', 'tn' : 'Trinda Noober',
       'fj' : 'Freetus Jaunders', 'nt' : 'Ninar Tetris', 
       'gm' : 'Gloobin Marfo', 'nk' : 'Niche Kaguya',
       'bd' : 'Brent Drago', 'vt' : 'Volga Toober',
       'kt' : 'Kinser Talebearing', 'br' : 'Bnola Rae',
       'nb' : 'Nugget Beano', 'yk' : 'Yeldstat Krong',
       'gy' : 'Gelliot Yabelor', 'il' : 'Illetia Dorfson',
       'ct' : 'Can Tabber', 'tv' : 'Trinoba Vyder'}

    campers_outside_theater = random.sample(campers.keys(), 5)
    people = campers_outside_theater + ['Troid, the counselor from the bus.']
    choices = '\n\n'.join('%d. %s' % (i + 1, campers[p]) for (i, p) in enumerate(people))
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what key error?

Comment: Can you supply us with the traceback please?

Comment: Im sorry I'm new at this how would i copy the traceback here from the windows powershell??

Comment: @lerugray Where did you see the error, copy/paste here

Comment: If you're on Python 3, dict `keys` returns a view. `random.sample` needs a sequence. Use `list(campers)` instead of `campers.keys()` instead. (I suspect you'll immediately run into the next bug if you do, though.) I think you would have gotten a TypeError instead of a KeyError if this were the problem, though.

Comment: Its on python 2.7, I was getting key errors before this and now i just got a new error, sorry this is so disorganized.

Comment: ...that's a `NameError`. What is `keys(people)` supposed to do? Did you ever define it? There's no such built-in operation.

Comment: I edited the code and got rid of that as it was another bug. still getting the same error tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you pretty much what you want:

```
import random
campers = {'pb' : 'Pooder Bennet', 'jf' : 'Jupiter Fargo',
           'rb' : 'Randy Buffet', 'bl' : 'Botany Lynn',
       'bt' : 'Boris Tortavich', 'tn' : 'Trinda Noober',
       'fj' : 'Freetus Jaunders', 'nt' : 'Ninar Tetris', 
       'gm' : 'Gloobin Marfo', 'nk' : 'Niche Kaguya',
       'bd' : 'Brent Drago', 'vt' : 'Volga Toober',
       'kt' : 'Kinser Talebearing', 'br' : 'Bnola Rae',
       'nb' : 'Nugget Beano', 'yk' : 'Yeldstat Krong',
       'gy' : 'Gelliot Yabelor', 'il' : 'Illetia Dorfson',
       'ct' : 'Can Tabber', 'tv' : 'Trinoba Vyder'}

campers_outside_theater = random.sample(campers.keys(), 5)
people = campers_outside_theater #+ ['Troid, the counselor from the bus.']
choices = '\n\n'.join('%d. %s' % (i + 1, campers[p]) for (i, p) in enumerate(people))
print(choices)
```

you had `keys(people)`, but there is no such animal - that was your first error.  It was not a `KeyError`, but a `NameError` (since `keys` was never defined).  Then when I removed keys and just had `enumerate(people)` you got an actual key error because you were trying to use `'Troid, the counselor from the bus.'` as a key... but it isn't one.  I'm assuming you want to include him in people on the bus, but you will have to do it a different way.  Perhaps include him in your campers dictionary, and always add him to your keys after you take the random sample.

Comment: can i ask what #+ is doing? is that python 3? never seen it before.

Comment: That is commenting out everything after `#`.  If you uncomment it, you will get an error because there is no key in campers called `Troid, the ...`.  As I stated above, you should think about adding him to the dictionary somehow to keep things clean.

Comment: I see, this is the first bug ive made in my code! haha, i gotta figure out how to make specific non camper npcs show up, perhaps a dict of ALL characters :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is what is causing your error:

```
choices = '\n\n'.join('%d. %s' % (i + 1, campers[p]) for (i, p) in enumerate(people))
```

The reason is because of this line:

```
people = campers_outside_theater + ['Troid, the counselor from the bus.']
```

There is no name in the dictionary `campers` called `Troid, the counselor from the bus.`

To fix this:

```
>>> campers.update([('Troid', 'the counselor from the bus.')])
```